# urllib.request => AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, urllib, attributeerror

I get an attribute error on my code with the  method = 'POST' of my urllib.request.Request

I already try different syntax :

```py
POST = 'post'
method = POST

method = 'POST'
```

and others...

```py
request_login = urllib.request.Request("https://www.netflix.com/fr/Login",
    data = "userLoginId={}&password={}&rememberMe=false&flow=websiteSignUp&mode=login&action=loginAction&withFields=rememberMe%2CnextPage%2CuserLoginId%2Cpassword%2CcountryCode%2CcountryIsoCode&authURL=authURL%2FEcpWPKhtag%3D&nextPage=&showPassword=&countryCode=%2B33&countryIsoCode=FR".format(email, password),
    headers ={"""
    'Host': 'www.netflix.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.netflix.com/fr/',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': 330,
    """},
    unverifiable = True,
    method = POST)
```

output of error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\checker netflix.py", line 44, in <module>
    checkPassword(email,password)
  File ".\checker netflix.py", line 23, in checkPassword
    method = POST)
  File "C:\Users\Naylor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 334, in __init__
    for key, value in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I expect to success the request and parse the server response to see if the parameter of the data pass or be refused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers you're passing is a set containing a string:

```
headers ={"""
    'Host': 'www.netflix.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.netflix.com/fr/',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': 330,
    """}
```

instead of a dictionary:

```
headers = {
    'Host': 'www.netflix.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.netflix.com/fr/',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': 330,
    }
```